# EU Applying for Irish Citizenship, parent never had Foreign Birth Registration certification

Tags: immigration, citizenship, ireland

I'm applying for my Irish Citizenship form the UK so that I can live and work there.

I believe I qualify for Irish citizenship because of the following:

- a) I was born outside of Ireland before the 31st of December 2004 and
  after 1986.
- b) I have Irish born Great-Grandparents.
- c) My Father is
  adamant he completed his Foreign Birth Registration (FBR) before I was
  born.

While going through the process I realised my Father does not have an FBR certificate, so I go to apply for a replacement, the form for which asks how the original FBR certificate was lost/destroyed/stolen.

I can't complete the form for a replacement because my father claims he never had one,  and looking online I can't find any indication that he *would not* have received one when he registered.

So is it possible to complete a Foreign Born Registration without getting a certificate? And how would we go about getting one now?

Or does this mean my Father never registered and is in fact misremembering?

Comment: Did the Irish FBR registration office ever receive registration from your father? I would expect they'd have an alpha/date index.

Comment: I've emailed citizenshipinfo@justice.ie with the same question, he seems to think he did.

Comment: @ Charlie Tizzard Ó Kevlahan Who is the "he" in your comment above: your father or someone within the Irish bureaucracy?

Comment: Sorry, it's my father